# Gather individual record for the last three days

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains three things: a start number, an end number, and a date which look something like this:

table: number2day

```
first       last        day
109288787   136388928   2013-06-29
136388929   144276079   2013-06-30
144276080   147295660   2013-07-01
```

Given today's date, I need to find the first value from days ago so I can compare it to a number within another query

I know that there is `WHERE <col-name> IN (SUBQUERY)` syntax but there is a similar statement that can use operators? `>`,`<`,`=`?

Something like:

```
WHERE num >= (SELECT first FROM number2day WHERE day = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 3))
```

Here I only want to check if `num` is greater than `first` from 3 days ago. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for showing this subquery syntax, it will be useful in my SQL learning journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html) keyword should work for you here:

```
WHERE NUM >= ALL (SELECT first FROM number2day WHERE day = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 3))
```

Comment: excellent! I knew what I was looking for, just not what it was called. Thanks.

Comment: Gonna add this to my notebook because `ALL` will come in handy at some point. Need to do more reading to figure out this subquery syntax though :)